# DataFormat.Error: We reached the end of the buffer error from Power BI + Source Data from Azure Blob

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I am using Power Source as Azure Blob Storage folder. While connecting the JSON file from Azure Blob Storage facing an error "DataFormat.Error: We reached the end of the buffer".

Please share any solution related to this issue.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please share the complete error details and explain the complete process. when are you facing the issue and what steps did you try to overcome the issue ?